# How is this kind of cattle called?

Tags: meat, beef, veal

I've heard of beef, not specifically "veal", where the animal can be older but has had mostly a milk diet and been restricted of physical movement, preventing muscle development, making for softer and more tender cuts of meat throughout the whole animal. Is this true? What's this meat called?

Comment: Certainly sounds like veal to me, and the nasty kind as well.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall If you mean "nasty" like I assume you mean, I concur. I'm a carnivore, but I draw the line at veal. That's just cruel.

Comment: @Jolenealaska. You might be interested to know that in the UK, we produce 'rose veal' - the calves are treated differently, under the auspices of the RSPCA, the meat is pink in colour, and usually, it's bull calves which have been produced by dairy cows; these would otherwise have been slaughtered at birth, given they can't produce milk.

Comment: The length of the life means much less than the quality. Is this "veal" that doesn't involve unreasonable bondage? I'm all for that. Even if I don't care to eat it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cattle you're referring to are Japanese [Waygu](http://luciesfarm.com/artman/publish/article_39.php) - there are a number of breeds under this rubric, but there are notable points:

- Genetic predisposition to exceptional marbling and tenderness
- The animals are hand-massaged by the farmer, due to insufficient space for the cattle to wander freely
- Grain fed rather than grass fed, as the cattle is generally tethered or penned for its life.

Answer (score 0):

A heifer is a young cow that hasn't had babies yet, but it eats like a regular cow.

Answer (score -1):

Are you referring to [Kobe beef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobe_beef) perhaps?